# Login failed while generating report

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I changed password of database after that i am facing this error. How can I resolve this?

> Logon failed. Details: ADO Error Code: 0x Source: Microsoft OLE DB
>   Provider for SQL Server Description: Login failed for user 'TANUser'.
>   SQL State: 42000 Native Error:  Error in File
>   C:\Windows\TEMP\temp}.rpt: Unable to connect: incorrect log on
>   parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the password that is set in your ConnectionInfo to your new password:

```
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.Password = "DatabasePassword";
```